# index.wsgi not finding virtualenv in root

Tags: django, apache, virtualenv, wsgi

I am trying to install a django site on an Apache VPS, following this [tutorial](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/)
my index.wsgi should activate a virtualenv in the root, it looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/DBENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/DB2015/')
sys.path.append('/home/DB2015/davidcms/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'davidcms.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/DBENV/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

and I get this error

```
[Tue Feb 17 07:13:30.701511 2015] [:error] [pid 16103:tid 140396130674432]           [client 217.44.75.146:58169]     execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
[Tue Feb 17 07:13:30.701653 2015] [:error] [pid 16103:tid 140396130674432] [client 217.44.75.146:58169] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/.virtualenvs/DBENV/bin/activate_this.py'
```

So its looking in `var/www/` instead of the root. When I try to change `os.path.expanduser` to just the path to .virtualenvs in the root as such:

```
# Activate your virtual env
activate_env= "~/.virtualenvs/DBENV/bin/activate_this.py"
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
```

it still says

```
[Tue Feb 17 07:17:12.019641 2015] [:error] [pid 16104:tid 140396206208768] [client 217.44.75.146:58200]     execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
[Tue Feb 17 07:17:12.019852 2015] [:error] [pid 16104:tid 140396206208768] [client 217.44.75.146:58200] IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/.virtualenvs/DBENV/bin/activate_this.py'
```

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably Apache is not running as you, but as its own user, so it won't use your home directory.

You shouldn't really have your code in a home directory anyway. Pick a standard place - eg a new top-level directory like `/srv`, or `/var/sites`, or something.

Comment: and put the virtualenv in there?

Comment: Yes, and use an absolute path.

Comment: thank you! I think that solved it. 
getting other errors now but let's not get into those :)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a relatively new issue or possibly a bug?? I couldn't find anything but a few recent posts (and maybe a bug report or two) related to the issues both David and I were experiencing.

I use virtualenvwrapper to manage my VEs,
and as anyone familiar with it knows, you can access the VE by navigating to a directory like "~/.virtualenvs/whaterver".

Well according to [this](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Wikilearn/TildeSlash): *~/ (tilde slash): The tilde is a Linux "shortcut" to denote a user's home directory.*

That means you can also access the VE by navigating to "/home/username/.virtualenvs/" (which is the absolute path that wsgi is looking for).

[**WSGI config**]

I was able to get my Django welcome page to run by modifying my index.wsgi file like so:

```
    ------------
    # Changed From:

    # Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
    site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

    # Activate your virtual env 
    activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/bin/activate_this.py")

    ------------
    # Changed To:

    # Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
    site.addsitedir('/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

    # Activate your virtual env 
    activate_env=os.path.expanduser('/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/bin/activate_this.py')
```

**Important**: When setting things up in the same manner as I have listed here it is imperative that you *do not* specify a wsgi file in your django project's settings.py (It seems to be the case that it's auto generated when a new project is created from django-admin). On my system when both files were getting loaded I could not get a response from Django and my browser would hang saying "loading" indefinitely and no messages were being posted to the apache error.log file, though "some" errors from django would make it to the browser if debug=true. So if you have a line like this in settings.py:

- WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'

Make sure to comment it out or just remove it (took me an hour or two of hair ripping before I noticed the conflict)

[**Updating old examples**]

I did however run into an issue being generated from my wsgi file. If you get an error similar to:
*"AppRegistryNotReady: The translation infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is ready. Check that you don't make non-lazy gettext calls at import time."*

That's the error i received when trying to configure django for apache using this procedure:

- [**Deploy Django on Apache with Virtualenv and mod_wsgi**](http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/).

  ```
  #Make sure you are not doing this
  import django.core.handlers.wsgi
  application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

  #And rather you should be doing this
  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
  application = get_wsgi_application()
  ```

According to this [django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/deployment/wsgi/) that is (now) the proper way to construct your wsgi file.

[**File permissions**]

It is also a good idea to set the proper group and ownership of all the files in your django project directories.
I prefer to keep both the ownership and group as the user for the VE I'm configuring.

This can be done by running the commands:

- sudo chown -R username /home/django_projects/myproject
- sudo chgrp -R username /home/django_projects/myproject

[**My specs**]

- Ubuntu server 14.10
- Apache 2.4.10
- Django 1.7.4

[**My apache config**]

I have configured a virtualhost so I can access my django app from port 8080 on the local network. This also allows me to set the path to my VE python by configuring the WSGIPythonHome directive. Also I run wsgi in daemon mode to use the WSGIDaemonProcess directive to specify which user the daemon thread should run as.

```
#My awesome django app's apache config
WSGIPythonHome /home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv #This is important and sets the path that apache/wsgi uses to the virtualenv's python.
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        #ServerAdmin [email protected]
        ServerName mydomain.com
        #ServerAlias www.mydomain.com

        #Must run as daemon so the delegated process can inherit the virtualenvs user 
        WSGIDaemonProcess SomeProcessGroupName user=username group=username processes=2 threads=5 home=/var/www/my-site.com/
        WSGIProcessGroup SomeProcessGroupName 
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/my-site.com/index.wsgi

        Alias /static /var/www/my-site.com/static/
        <Location "/static/">
            #Options -Indexes
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

[**My dir structure**]

```
|
|_var
|   |_www
|       |_my-site.com
|           |_index.wsgi
|           |_static
|               |_css
|               |_js
|_home
|   |_django_projects
|   |   |_projectbase
|   |       |_myproject
|   |       |   |_myproject
|   |       |       |_settings.py
|   |       |
|   |       |_templates
|   |
|   |_username
|       |_.virtualenvs
|           |_myprojectenv
|               |_bin
|                   |_activate_this.py
|_etc
    |_apache2
        |_apache2.conf
```

[**My python path**]

```
# Printed from python console in my virtual environment

/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages


# printed to the apache log from within settings.py

/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7',
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
/home/username/.virtualenvs/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
/usr/lib/python2.7',
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
/home/username/.virtualenvs/Horizon_Server_Env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
/home/django-projects/projectbase/myproject',
/home/django-projects/projectbase/myproject/myproject'
```

[**Summery**]

I have documented some of the steps I've taken during my experience with configuring Django to run in accordance with the tutorial David and I were using. As I stated before my application runs on a local network (on port 8080) and is inaccessible to the internet. So this configuration was for my needs and may not meet your security requirement (though I would love to get some other people's input on that subject!!). And as stated earlier by Daniel R. you might want to consider locating your virtual environment in a top level directory. However I feel the above mentioned is a nice way to run that tutorial without having to make many alterations to their examples.
Hope this helps out!